# Prove min(L) = all words in L that they don't have any prefix of themselves in L

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

We define the minimal words language of $L, \min(L)$, to be the language of all words in $L$ that don't have any prefix in $L$.

Assume $L$ is regular language.
I need to prove by building an automaton that $\min(L)$ is regular.

Comment: Welcome at math.SE! You can use $\LaTeX$ here, e.g. `$L$` would look like $L$, for more see [FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq), it is very helpful. Also, could you please fix the spelling of your post (e.g. use the browser build-in spellchecker)? Some people might find the quality of your question insulting.

Comment: Look, for example, at the edits I just made. Click on the link after the word "edited" and then look at the source, by clicking on "source".

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider a deterministic automaton, if you happen to be at the accepting state, anything that comes later should send you to the "trash" state.